# How to show resume on jsp from database ? I am using Hibernate and Struts2

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

1.Action Class :

```
public String getResumeNames(){     
    list=resumeServiceImpl.getResumeNames();
    return "success";
}
```

2.Service class :

```
public List<DocumentRepository> getResumeNames() {      
    list=viewResumeDaoImpl.getAllResumeNames();
    return list;
}
```

3.DAO Class :

```
public List<DocumentRepository> getAllResumeNames() {       
    try{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
      list=(List<DocumentRepository>)session.createCriteria(DocumentRepository.class).list();
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

JSP

```xml
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>        
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function fun(rdval) {
                var s = rdval.value;
                alert(s);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <s:form action="getResume">
            <s:iterator value="list">
                <input type="radio" name="rid" 
                      value='<s:property value="documentId"/>'  
                   onchange="fun(this)" />
                <s:property value="documentName" />
                <br />
            </s:iterator>
            <s:submit value="Display resume"></s:submit>
        </s:form>
    </body>

</html>
```

I took all the value in list.i gave view link in front of all name.but when I click in view link ,a new jsp get open named viewResume.jsp in viewResume.jsp how to display resume ?

Comment: Pass unique id, fetch record using this uid and display it.

Answer (score 0):

In Action

```
private long rid; // with Setter
private DocumentRepository resume; // with Getter

public String getResume(){     
    resume=resumeServiceImpl.getResumeById(rid);
    return "success";
}
```

In JSP

```xml
<s:property value="resume.id" />
<s:property value="resume.creationDate" />
<s:property value="resume.dudesname"   />
```

But since it seems you are at the beginning, I suggest you to consider using Java EE features like JPA2 (with Hibernate as implementation) instead of raw Hibernate, [completely abandoning the DAO concept](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jpa_ejb3_killed_the_dao).

Comment: what the use of 'resume.creationDate' here ??

Comment: The same of "dude's name", it's only an example; since we don't know the structure of your object, I invented a couple of fields just to give you the idea